# Local Network Hyperlinks in the New ArcGIS Online Map Viewer

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap, html-popup

So this always worked in the old map viewer. I have a local link:

```
\\server\path\path2\webpage.html
```

I could create a custom link in the old map viewer using pop ups like this:

```
file://server/path/path2/webpage{attribute}.html
```

But when I enter this now into a text at the bottom of the pop up, it simply opens a new tab with my same map viewer? I've tried some other options:

```
file:///server\path\path2\webpage{attribute}.html

//server\path\path2\webpage{attribute}.html

file://Z:/path/path2/webpage{attribute}.html
```

Nothing seems to be working, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am operating within the ArcGIS Portal 11.0 Map Viewer and get a similar result to yours. It looks as though this a known limitation of the new Map Viewer. I found the statement, "Note that only https links are supported", within an ESRI article: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/configure-pop-ups-custom-attribute-display/
[image]